# NEST query not returning data for a Metricbeat field, held in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, metricbeat

I am trying to query metricbeat data held in elasticsearch and I'm looking for two fields: `host` and `system.cpu.total.pct`. Both are contained in my class:

```
public string Host { get; set; }
[Number(NumberType.ScaledFloat, Name = "system.cpu.total.pct")]
public float Cpu_pct { get; set; }
```

And this is my query:

```
var searchResponse = client.Search<System>(s => s
            .Query(q => q
                .Bool(b => b
                    .Filter(bf => bf
                        .Range(r => r
                            .Field(f => f.Cpu_pct)
                            .GreaterThan(0)
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        );
```

There is data in the index with documents, that have the `system.cpu.total.pct` above `0`, but when I print out the response documents `Cpu_pct` only outputs `0`, yet `host` gives the correct hostname.

Why I can't return the value in `system.cpu.total.pct`?

Comment: Is the field called `"system.cpu.total.pct"` in Elasticsearch, or is that a dot notation path to a `"pct"` field on `"total"`, on `"cpu"`, on `"system"` object?

Comment: The latter, i am pretty sure that is where i am going wrong i am just not sure how to get a field within a number of nested objects

Comment: Max have you find the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Update the `System` type to match the hierarchy of inner objects within the JSON source

```
public class System
{
    public Cpu Cpu { get; set; }
}

public class Cpu
{
    public Total Total { get; set; }
}

public class Total
{
    public float Pct { get; set; }
}
```

Now upon deserialization, the value will be set for the  `Source.Cpu.Total.Pct` property.